# Unable to parse JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

i have problem to parse `json`.

This is my json:

```
{
success: true,
outputScenario: "Default",
data: {
output: [
{
titolo: "Esterna di Mattia e Vittoria - 6 novembre",
sottotitolo: "En plein air",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Giorgia - 6 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Un primo incontro molto schietto",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: ""Sono fatto così"",
sottotitolo: "Mattia è molto infastidito da alcuni commenti nei suoi riguardi",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: ""Occhi da gatta... morta!"",
sottotitolo: "Tra Ester e Angela non corre buon sangue....",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Angela - 6 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Caldarroste e chiarimenti",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna di Paolo e Ester - 6 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Metti una serata... "romantica"",
date: "06/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: ""Sei la persona a cui penso di più"",
sottotitolo: "Nella prossima puntata del Trono Classico...",
date: "05/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna inedita di Paolo e Silvia - 3 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Un'esterna vintage!",
date: "03/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna inedita di Mattia e Angela - 3 novembre",
sottotitolo: "L'esterna mancata",
date: "03/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna inedita di Paolo e Laura - 3 novembre",
sottotitolo: "A lezione di tedesco!",
date: "03/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Esterna inedita di Sabrina e Federico - 3 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Sfida a tutta velocità",
date: "03/11/2017"
},
{
titolo: "Venerdì 3 novembre",
sottotitolo: "Sabrina e Alex tra critiche e arrabbiature...",
date: "03/11/2017"
}
]
},
stateToken: "eyJqYXIiOnsidmVyc2lvbiI6InRvdWdoLWNvb2tpZUAyLjMuMiIsInN0b3JlVHlwZSI6Ik1lbW9yeUNvb2tpZVN0b3JlIiwicmVqZWN0UHVibGljU3VmZml4ZXMiOnRydWUsImNvb2tpZXMiOltdfSwidmVyc2lvbiI6MX0=",
cookies: [ ]
}
```

i get the follow error in my app:`Json parsing error: Value`

I don't know why!

this is my code to parse json:

```
  HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("output");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        Video video=new Video();
                        String titolo = c.getString("titolo");
                        String sottotitolo = c.getString("sottotitolo");
                        String data = c.getString("date");
                        video.setTitolo(titolo);
                        video.setSottotitolo(sottotitolo);
                        video.setData(data);




                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                    /*    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);*/


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        videoList.add(video);
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
```

Who can help me? i am not able to find the error!

Comment: Make sure your json is correct in post. Invalid json format in question so you cannot parse and deserialize json until you have valid json.

Answer (score 0):

## Why it doesn't work

The provided JSON is not JSON, you can check [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/),but the unquoted strings are not allowed in JSON.

## How to fix

The first step of fixing this would be to quote the key strings

## More info on JSON rules

You can find the full set of rules that define JSON [here](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jrtapsell, but I noticed you also need to properly escape double quotes in your string, for example, in some of the 'titolo' fields, if you want to keep the " in the string you need to escape it by adding a backslash (\) right before it, because it is a special character.